# View customer info on select change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm creating a page which will allow an admin to select a user from a drop down list, which populates from a database.  When the person is selected, the info associated with that person will then be viewed on the page.  I already have a select statement which selects all the info and the drop down menu is populating correctly.  However, I'm unsure on how to get that selected user's info to display on the page once selected.  Would I need to do an entirely different select statement and query which checks which customer was selected?  Or is there another way?

**customer.php**

```
<div id="view_form" class="view">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="viewCustomer">Select Customer</label>
            <?php
                echo "<select name='selectCust' id='selectCust'>";
                echo "<option></option>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custResult)){
                    $name = "{$row['fName']} {$row['lName']}";
                    echo "<option>$name</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**viewUser.php**

```
if(isset($search)){
    $select = "SELECT * FROM $cust WHERE acctNum='{$search}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $select);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $acct = "{$row['acctNum']}";
            echo $acct;
        }
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function searchAjax(){
        var search = $('#selectCust').val();
        $.post('includes/viewUser.php', {searchUsers: search}, function(data){
            $('#view_form').append(data);
        })
    }       
    $('#selectCust').on('change', function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        searchAjax();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Search.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript "src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".dropdown-users").on("change",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        search_ajax_way();
        });

    });

    function search_ajax_way(){
        var search_this=$("dropdown-users").val();

        $.post("Ajaxsearch.php", {searchusers : search_this}, function(data){
            $(".results").html(data);   
        })
    }
    </script>

    <div id="view_form" class="view">
        <form method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="viewCustomer">Select Customer</label>
                <?php
                    echo "<select class="dropdown-users">";
                    echo "<option></option>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custResult)){
                        $name = "{$row['fName']} {$row['lName']}";
                        $acct = $row['acctNum'];
                        echo "<option value="$acct">$name ($acct)</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>



    <label>Enter</label>
    <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="What You Are Looking For?" size="50"/>
    <input type="<span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">submit</span>" <span id="IL_AD6" class="IL_AD">value</span>="Search" id="button_find" />

    <div class="results"></div>
```

//************************************************************************************************
************************************************************************************************//

Ajaxsearch.php

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); // Enter your information here
    $term = $_POST['searchusers']
    $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $term);
    if($term == "")
        echo "Enter Something to search";
    else {
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from USERDATEBASEHERE where ID = '{$term}' ");
        $string = '';

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {

            if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
               $string = "{$row['ID']}";
            }

        } else {
            $string = "This Person does not exist";
        }

            echo $string;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any references I could use so I can learn how to do this?  I've never tried mixing PHP and AJAX.

Comment: Do you still require this if you do i will write it now

Comment: I do.  I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

Comment: just added some code i haven't tested it and obviously some of it you will need to change to your database information etc.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  I'll use this as a reference and play around with it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to try it yet.  Had something else come up that's taking precedence.  I'll be able to tell you yay or nay by tonight though. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't had the chance to even work on this project since last week.  I will be working on it tonight though and will give you a yea or nay tonight.

Comment: I got everything implemented and added, however, I'm not seeing any results when I select a user from the drop down menu.  I've edited my question to show what I did with each file.

Comment: from what i can see your not giving it the account number for that user? as a value on the select box

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="view_form" class="view">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="viewCustomer">Select Customer</label>
            <?php
                echo "<select name=\"somename\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\">";
                echo "<option value=\"\">Select User</option>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($custResult)){
                    $name = "{$row['fName']} {$row['lName']}";
                    $acct = $row['acctNum'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$acct.'">$name ($acct)</option>';
                }
                echo "</select>";
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The options must have some refering value, through which you can retrieve the details of selected user, whenever the value of option is not initiated then the default value of the option will be option's label.

Comment: This didn't even address the question.  All you did was add a value attribute to the option tags and created an imaginary submit function in the select tag.